# Question regaring accessing Dojo Components

Tags: dojo

For example when i tried this with

```
 <input type="text" name="myButton" id="myButton"  dojoType="dijit.form.Button"
        required="true" />

 <script type="text/javascript">
            dojo.addOnLoad(function() {

dojo.connect(dojo.byId('myButton'), 'onclick', myFunction);
            });
        </script>
```

This above example works fine .
But i am having a query , i have seen a similar example .

which it uses

```
  dojo.connect(dijit.byId("InputText"),"onKeyUp",checkForEnterKey);
```

My question is how can we know for what component should we use either dijit.byId or dojo.byId
**dojo.byId and dijit.byId**

Please tell me , thank you very much for reading .

Answer (score 0):

`dojo.byId` works on DOM notes.  `dijit.byId` allows you to access dijit data.

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/info.html

Comment: But to acess the Button , i am  using dojo.byId('myButton') , its not a DOM know .

Comment: It is in the DOM - it's the name of the input field you provided in your question.